# Functions in C, Codeblocks error: expected '=', ',', ';',

Tags: c, compiler-errors, syntax-error, codeblocks

I'm currently working on this code just for experience, I am currently coming across several errors in which I do not understand, I've only been programming for a month hence i lack the knowledge about the errors and coding.I can create the program in just the main function easily but, I want to practice functions that's why i designed the program with several functions.

s tut\lab\main.c|15|error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before '{' token| <--- 
^^^^i'm encountering this error in several lines,
lines: 15,36,41,54,58.

this are the instructions to the program, if Someone could help me that would be great, as in refining my code(just to compare on what i could have done or missed) or how to fix the error. Thanks

Chatflow Wireless offers customers 600 weekday minutes for a flat rate of
39.99. Night (8 P.M. to 7 A.M. ) and weekend minutes are free, but additional
weekday minutes cost 0.40 each. There are taxes of 5.25% on all charges.
Write a program that prompts the user to enter the number of weekday minutes,
night minutes, and weekend minutes used, and calculates the monthly
bill and average cost of a minute before taxes. The program should display
with labels all the input data, the pretax bill and average minute cost, the
taxes, and the total bill. Store all monetary values as whole cents (rounding
the taxes and average minute cost), and divide by 100 for display of results.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define FLATE_RATE 39.99; /* basic water demand charge */
#define PLAN_MINUTES 600; /* charge per thousand gallons used */
#define ADD_MINUTES 0.40;
#define TAX 0.0525;

void instruct;
int compBill(int minutesUsed);
void displayBill(double bill,double extraCharge)


int main()
{
int minutesUsed,weekendUsed,nightUsed,extraCharge;
int totalMinutes = minutesUsed + weekendUsed + nightUsed;

instruct();

printf("enter weekday minutes used (8am-7pm) : ");
scanf(" %d",&minutesUsed);
printf("enter weekend minutes used : ");
scanf(" %d",&weekendUsed);
printf("enter night minutes used : ");
scanf(" %d",&nightUsed);

int compBill(minutesUsed);
displayBill();



return 0;
}

void instruct()){
printf("Hello, welcome\n");
printf("I will calculate your total phone bill\n");
printf("We have a flat rate of $%lf  and $0.40 per weekday minute    used\n",FLATE_RATE);
return;
}
int compBill(int minutesUsed){
double bill;
double extraCharge;

if (minutesUsed>PLAN_MINUTES){
extraCharge = ((double)minutesUsed - PLAN_MINUTES)*ADD_MINUTES;
bill = extraCharge + FLATE_RATE;
}
else {
bill = FLATE_RATE;
}
return (bill);
}
void displayBill(){
prinf("your phone bill total is  $%lf ",bill);
printf("you went over your total minutes so there's an extra charge of %lf",extraCharge);
return;
}
```

Comment: `void instruct;` --> `void instruct(void);`, `void instruct()){`--> `void instruct(void){` There are much typo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue is the use of semicolons on the defines:

```
#define FLATE_RATE 39.99; /* basic water demand charge */
#define PLAN_MINUTES 600; /* charge per thousand gallons used */
#define ADD_MINUTES 0.40;
#define TAX 0.0525;
```

When they are substituted, it will *also include the semicolon*. You almost never want this.  Instead you should say simply:

```
#define FLATE_RATE 39.99 /* basic water demand charge */
#define PLAN_MINUTES 600 /* charge per thousand gallons used */
#define ADD_MINUTES 0.40
#define TAX 0.0525
```

Comment: the syntax problem was solved, but i'm getting issues with the program my functions aren't working properly, can u give me some insight on what i'm doing wrong? thank u

Comment: Your best bet is to open a new question and elaborate on what specifically is not working the way you want/expect.

Answer (score 2):

Try also adding semicolon after this line and see what happens:

```
void displayBill(double bill,double extraCharge)
```